# stored procedure not returning value on SQL Server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i have a stored procedure which i am trying to execute from my DAO implementation class. but i am failing to get any result. on my list i see return values as null.

my DAO code which executes stored procedure

**Edited Dao:**

```
 @Repository
 public class OhlcDaoImpl implements OhlcDao {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;

 public List getOhlc(Result result) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("EXEC getOhlc :stockSymbol, :statementType, :financialDataTypeId, :fiscalYearId");
 query.setString("stockSymbol",result.getStockSymbol());
 query.setString("statementType",result.getStatementType());
 query.setInteger("financialDataTypeId",result.getFinancialDataTypeId());
 query.setInteger("fiscalYearId",result.getFiscalYearId());

 List l = query.list();
return l;
}
}
```

I tried to change setparameters to setInteger for int field but still no result.

**DefaultController.java**

controller class calls service and service calls dao. service has nothing but one interface class with getData method and one implementation class.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getData",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List getData(@RequestBody Result result){
    List l =ohlcService.getData(result);
    return l;
}
```

my stored procedure

```
USE [Wealth_1_0_0_Srv]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[getOhlc]
(
@stockSymbol varchar(50),
@statementType varchar(50),
@financialDataTypeId int,
@fiscalYearId int
)
As
Begin
Set Nocount on;
Set Arithabort on;

Select    fdd.FinancialHeadId,isnull(ftd.FinancialHeadText,fh.FinancialHeadName)FinancialHeadName,fdd.Value,isnull(ftd.Bold,0)Bold,isnull(ftd.RowSeq,0)RowSeq
from FinancialDataMast fdm
    inner join FinancialDataDetl fdd on fdd.MastId=fdm.Id
    inner join FinancialHeading fh on fh.Id=fdd.FinancialHeadId
    inner join Stock s on s.Id=fdm.StockId
    INNER JOIN StatementType st ON st.Id = fdm.StatementTypeId
    left outer join FinancialTemplateMast ftm on ftm.StatementTypeId=fdm.StatementTypeId and ftm.SectorId=s.SectorId and ftm.FinancialReportType=(Case fdm.FinancialDataTypeId when 0 then 2 else 1 end)
    left outer join FinancialTemplateDetl ftd on ftd.MastId=ftm.Id and ftd.FinancialHeadId=fdd.FinancialHeadId
where s.StockSymbol=@stockSymbol and st.StatementTypeName=@statementType and fdm.FinancialDataTypeId=@financialDataTypeId  and fdm.FiscalYearId=@fiscalYearId
order by isnull(ftd.RowSeq,0) asc
End
```

my parameters are fine. on debug mode i can see them but i am not getting any result set.

Comment: Did you try executing the stored procedure on the management studio with the same parameter values? Is it giving any results?

Comment: the procedure while executing on sql management studio perfectly returns values.

Comment: Can you post the full class that is making the call?

Comment: please check the edited question above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling procedure, which doesn't return value-just perform query inside, you should create function.

Comment: What's wrong with the stored procedure? Do you know how a stored procedure returns a result set?

Comment: I tought it works similar to Oracle pl/sql, but it seams I'm wrong:/ sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("stockSymbol %s, statementType %s, financialDataTypeId %d, fiscalYearId %d", result.getStockSymbol(), result.getStatementType(), result.getFinancialDataTypeId(), result.getFiscalYearId()));

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("EXEC getOhlc :stockSymbol, :statementType, :financialDataTypeId, :fiscalYearId");
 query.setString("stockSymbol",result.getStockSymbol());
 query.setString("statementType",result.getStatementType());
 query.setInteger("financialDataTypeId",result.getFinancialDataTypeId());
 query.setInteger("fiscalYearId",result.getFiscalYearId());

List l = query.list();
```

Please add these lines in the hibernate configuration:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

or if you use log4j add this:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

This way you can check what is executed.

Comment: unfortunately it is also not working. it prints

stockSymbol ADBL, statementType Balance sheet, financialDataTypeId 0, fiscalYearId 16

which are parameters

Comment: and Hibernate: EXEC getOhlc ?, ?, ?, ?

on my console. i assume this means proc is running?

Comment: Can you check that this call returns data `EXEC getOhlc 'ADBL', 'Balance sheet', 0, 16`

Comment: no it does not. now when i checked into postman errors i see 

>HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

but still i don't find any data being returned when i check 
 queryReturns= arrayList size = 0 on debug mode

Comment: the query returns data while it is executed on sql management studio.

Comment: i am almost scratching my balls from yesterday and failing to complete this. 

i modified according to you suggestion still i get no data. and in console it prints Hibernate: CALL getOhlc(?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Change in the code this: SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("{call getOhlc(:stockSymbol, :statementType, :financialDataTypeId, :fiscalYearId)}");

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all to all those who replied. the issue was not on proc. it was mapping issue so i mapped all returned columns like this

```
query.addScalar("FinancialHeadId", IntegerType.INSTANCE);
query.addScalar("FinancialHeadName", StringType.INSTANCE);
query.addScalar("Value",IntegerType.INSTANCE);
query.addScalar("Bold",IntegerType.INSTANCE);
query.addScalar("RowSeq",IntegerType.INSTANCE);
```

and the problem was solved.